# Error propagation in microservices architecture

Tags: java, spring, rest

Let's say that I have 3 microservices - A,B and C.

Communication pattern through these services looks like 
this:
`A -> B -> C`.

Services `B` and `C` can throw exception and return 500 to caller. In service `A` I need to recognize whether service `B` or `C` thrown exception (returned 500). What are some common patterns for such problem ? I was thinking about:

- Adding to responses of `B` and `C` additional field which would represent service which caused issue and propagating it through services e.g. if service `C` would return 500 this field would be copied to response of service `B` and propagated to service `A`. On the other hand if service `B` would cause issue it would add this field to its 500 response with value representing service `B`.
- Recognizing which service caused exception by exception class or error message

Both approaches have cons - in first approach I would have to handle appending this field to responses and propagation of it from service `C` through service `B` to service `A` and if it would like to add this behaviour to more service it involves a lot of code duplication through services. On the other hand in case of second approach just feels wrong.

Do you know any patterns or maybe libraries/frameworks for such issue ?

Comment: Why does `A` need to know what error happened on `C`? One pro of microservices is decoupling. If `A` communicates with `B` only, `A` should not need to know about errors on `C`. It would be `B`'s responsibility to re-map the error message from `C` to something semantically meaningful for `A` (best without  mentioning service `C`).

Comment: Lets say that frontend uses ```A``` and ```C``` is gateway to external system owned by someone else. In frontend I would like to show two messages 'External system failed, contact external system owners' in case of failure in ```C``` and 'Our system failed, contact us' in case of failure in ```B```

Answer (score 1):

I and others at Google developed a solution for this based on Google's proprietary Java serving framework.

The best I can describe it in HTTP terms is as follows:

1. The solution makes available upstream (in Service A) the source of the error in the form of a `Service Error Trace`.
2. A `Service Error Trace` is similar to a Java stack trace, with the difference that the service error trace contains a list of Service/Endpoint tuples that represents the error propagation chain rather than Java classes and line numbers.
3. Each service is instrumented with an error handler that is responsible for building this error trace. Either creating it from scratch, or appending a new service error element to the trace. The handler then pushes this error upstream using the response side channel (In HTTP, response side channels are akin to HTTP response headers).
4. The first item in the `Service Error Trace` would be the source of error. The source of error is what I believe you are seeking after.

Hope that gives you some ideas for a project that fits your use case!

M.

Answer (score 0):

For this kind of typical problem, you have to use **Circuit Breaker Pattern**. I would suggest you to learn Hysterix a circuit breaker framework developped by Netflix team. Follow these links.

https://github.com/Netflix/Hystrix/wiki/How-it-Works

https://spring.io/guides/gs/circuit-breaker/

As commented by Turing85, Service A should not be impacted while calling service b and service c.

Comment: I think your answer does not answer my question

Comment: You can handle everything including custom message in circuit breaker fallback method so that everything will be handled gracefully. Besides there are other ways to handle manually. However, you can leverage circuit breaker functionality. The example on spring exactly describes your problem.

Comment: I believe Hystrix is being deprecated by the Spring Boot team.  There are other implementations that should be explored.  The circuit breaker recommendation is an excellent point.  https://spring.io/blog/2019/04/16/introducing-spring-cloud-circuit-breaker

Comment: While Circuit Breaker Pattern is intersting in general, it does not solve the problem of error propagation. The answer of @mshamma goes into the right direction